# How to invoke url with unicode text in java?

Tags: java, url, unicode

How to invoke url with unicode text in java ?

like : localhost:8080/abc?req=你已成

Please suggest the way to implement a client in RestFul webservice/

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/abc?req=" + URLEncoder.encode("你已成", "UTF-8");
```

See [URLEncoder.encode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

The question for a webservice usage example is a bit unspecific. Maybe look into http://rest.elkstein.org/

Comment: WebResource webResource = client     .resource("http://localhost:8080/testapp/rest/"+URLEncoder.encode("你已成", "UTF-8"));            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                   .get(ClientResponse.class);   Giving IllegalCharacter in URL exception

Comment: How did the URL look? (One thing to take care of is that the java source must be edited in the same UTF-8 or BIG5 encoding as the javac compiler uses.) URLEncoder then has the right Unicode text and can give an ASCII result.